# Efficiently parse a datafile into a laplacian matrix in Julia

Tags: matrix, julia

Given a data file

```
11616,,,6263,,,1.0
1429,,,5377,,,0.5
1429,,,7207,,,0.5
5377,,,7207,,,0.5
2713,,,1499,,,1.0
8598,,,1031,,,1.0
6166,,,1283,,,0.5
6166,,,12602,,,0.5
...
```

each entries obey the following structure and comes from the same connected graph
{node number1, node number 2, edge weight}(the parsing can be done easily so you may assume it is a 3-tuple data)
There is about ~100,000 entries. The matrix is guaranteed to be sparse.
How can I convert the these entries into a laplacian matrix and store the laplacian as a output file(or any Julia library I should look at)?

Comment: you can use the `sparse` command to build the sparse matrix from the vectors you get from the parsed data. However, there's no reason to use a sparse matrix for a Laplacian: just use a lazy type with overloaded indexing. You can use JLD.jl to save it to an output file.

Comment: Have a look at eg the MatrixNetworks.jl package.